# Overloading std::get for enum indexed array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11, enums

I find it rather convenient to have a class which basically acts like `std::array` but is indexed by values of some enum. I guess it's not very hard to imagine how to implement it, let's say it has a signature like this:

> ```
> class enum_array <typename EnumT, typename ValueT, size_t N>
> ```

On the other hand while trying to implement all of the standard `std::array` concerned functions I've noticed that writing overloaded `std::get` function for such class template is not that easy.

First of all, I think that it's only natural for this `std::get` to have value of aforementioned enum as a template argument and because of it the most of the problems emerge:

1) If I want to define such function outside the class I have to do something like:

> ```
> namespace std {
> template <EnumT Index, typename EnumT, typename ValueT, size_t N>
> EnumT &get (enum_array<EnumT, ValueT, N> &val)
> ```

But then the problem arouses that `EnumT` is still unknown while specifying the first template argument so this template is actually ill formed

If I put `EnumT Index` on the second or further place of argument list, then there's problem that I cannot really specify only this argument and will have to specify something else along with it and that will not look like normal `std::get` call on `std::array`.

2) If I define `get` function inside `enum_array` class as a friend function everything will be seemingly fine except the fact that then it'll be placed in the same namespace the class `enum_array` belongs to. And putting it in `namespace std` is not the best design.

So my question is: Can `std::get` with enum arguments be overloaded in a way that I mentioned for such class using C++ template mechanism?

(Want to point out that this question aroused mostly out of curiousity, afterall `std::get` is not the most useful function for `std::array` in my opinion)

Comment: I think you suffer from the (rather) common problem that there's no such thing as `template<auto Value>` (a template non-type parameter whose type is deduced). So, you either have to specify one function (template) per enum type, à la `template<first_enum Value> auto get(..);`, `template<second_enum Value> auto get(..);` etc., or you have to (manually) pass the type of the enum value for each invocation, à la `get<first_enum, Value0>(..);`, `get<second_enum, Value0>(..);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't yet. What you want is [Implicit Template Parameters](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html). The committee liked the idea but wanted to see a comparison of the proposed notation with the `auto` notation mentioned by dyp. I've promised a new draft for November's standards meeting. OK for me to include your example?

Comment: It sure is OK. Though there was an answer here that technically it's not legal to overload functions from `std`, so maybe it needs some reformulation to adhere to the standard precisely.

Comment: Understood, but that doesn't seem like much of an obstacle. You could use `using` statements to ensure that both `std::get` and `myns::get` participate in overload resolution. Since that's a little loosey-goosey, it might be better to have `myns::get` delegate to `std::get` for the cases it can't handle, etc. Now, if you have a template that expects to call `std::get` it won't find your functionality, but if it wants non-standard behavior, it should call something other than `std::get`.